# Как сдвинуть underline ниже ссылки используя css?

Tags: html, css

[image: Вот такой нужен отступ]

Нужно сделать underline ниже ссылки при наведении на неё, каким способом это можно осуществить?

```
<ul class="nav_list__content">
                    <a href=""><li class="nav_list__ul">Жилые комплексы</li></a>
                    <a href=""><li class="nav_list__ul">О компании</li></a>
                    <a href=""><li class="nav_list__ul">Контакты</li></a>
                    <a href=""><li class="nav_list__ul">Новости</li></a>
                    <a href=""><li class="nav_list__ul">Акции</li></a>
                    <a href=""><li class="nav_list__ul">Преимущества</li></a>
                </ul>
```

```
.nav_list__content{
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 50px;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
.nav_list__ul{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    transition: 0.8s;
    
}
.nav_list__ul:hover{

    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно сделать используя `border-bottom` и `padding-bottom`

```css
a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="Жилые комплексы">Жилые комплексы</a>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, всё работает, ваш совет тоже помог

Answer (score 4):

именно `underline` - никак, она жестко зафиксирована,

но можно создать имитацию и использовать `border-bottom` и `padding-bottom`, которым и определить отступ

```css
.link {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'link'>ссылка</div>
```

`
**P.S.**

стандартное подчеркивание лучше сбросить

```
text-decoration: none;
```

чтобы оно вдруг не помешало, если используются элементы с подчеркиванием, типа

```
<a class = 'link'>ссылка</a>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, всё работает

Answer (score 0):

Можно опустить вот пример

```
<a class="text" href="#">test</a>
```

```css
.text {
text-decoration: underline;
text-decoration-style: dashed;
text-underline-offset: 4px;
}
```

```html
<a class="text">test</a>
```

text-underline-offset за это отвечает